# Getting wrong values in HashMap

Tags: java, oop, object, hashmap

I have created HashMap for storing Brand:Car key value pair and inserted two car brands and their details.But on invoking .get(key) method I'm getting last stored values.

```
public class MapTest {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    MapTest map=new MapTest();
    map.test();

}
public void test() {
    HashMap<String,Car> vehicle=new HashMap<>();
    Details def=new Details();
    Car car=new Car();
    car.name="Mustang";
    def.model="SportsRoof";
    def.model_no=1969;
    def.color="Blue";
    car.features.add(def);
    vehicle.put("Ford",car);
    car.name="R8";
    def.model="Coupe";
    def.model_no=2009;
    def.color="Black";
    car.features.clear();
    car.features.add(def);
    vehicle.put("Audi",car);
    System.out.println(vehicle.get("Ford").name);
    System.out.println(vehicle.get("Ford").features.get(0).model);
    System.out.println(vehicle.get("Ford").features.get(0).model_no);
    System.out.println(vehicle.get("Ford").features.get(0).color);
}
```

Other Clsses

```
public class Car {
    String name;
    List<Details> features=new ArrayList<>();
    public Car() {

    }
}
public class Details {
    String model;
    int model_no;
    String color;
    public Details() {

    }
}
}
```

Output
R8
Coupe
2009
Black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reusing the same car object over and over again.  So, you've really not inserting different cars into the hashmap, you're inserting the *same* car object.  However, an unintended side effect is that when you change, e.g. the name of the car, you change it *everywhere* in the map.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
HashMap<String,Car> vehicle = new HashMap<>();
Details def= new Details();
Car car = new Car();
car.name = "Mustang";
def.model = "SportsRoof";
def.model_no = 1969;
def.color = "Blue";
car.features.add(def);
vehicle.put("Ford",car);
// create a new Car object
car = new Car();
car.name = "R8";
def.model = "Coupe";
def.model_no = 2009;
def.color = "Black";
car.features.clear();
car.features.add(def);
vehicle.put("Audi",car);
```

Comment: So I have to create two car objects ?

Answer (score 0):

In `Java` objects are stored based on `references`. You are initializing car variable only `one time` and assigning it to all keys of your `Map`.

You need to create different `Car` instances for different `keys` in your `Map`. And you need to create different instances of class `Details` too.